# Get rendered height of an html table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I'm working on a calendar for a webpage that is dynamically generated via javascript. However, I cannot seem to get the cells to all be the same height, unless they're all empty. I've put div's in each cell, set the width and height to fixed, set max-heights and max-widths, and no matter what, the table seems to ignore the CSS entirely and resize itself as it pleases. What makes the issue even more infuriating is that the difference between a filled table cell and an empty one is a mere 7 pixels.

My most recent idea was to write a javascript/jquery function that goes through the cells, finds the largest cell, and resizes all the other cells to be the same size as that one (I don't particularly care how big the cells are provided they are all the same width and height). However, I've discovered that jquery's height and width functions, when parsed to ints, simply return the CSS value set for height and width, or if no value was set (or the value was set as auto) return 0. Is there a function that will give me the absolute width and height of a table cell? Alternatively, is there a way to keep the dimensions of a table cell completely fixed (where regardless of content, they will not resize).

HTML:

```
<div id="calroot" hidden>
    <table id="calendar">
    <tr>
        <th class="day_spaces">Sunday</th>
        <th class="day_spaces">Monday</th>
        <th class="day_spaces">Tuesday</th>
        <th class="day_spaces">Wednesday</th>
        <th class="day_spaces">Thursday</th>
        <th class="day_spaces">Friday</th>
        <th class="day_spaces">Saturday</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="wk1"></tr>
    <tr id="wk2"></tr>
    <tr id="wk3"></tr>
    <tr id="wk4"></tr>
    <tr id="wk5"></tr>
    <tr id="wk6"></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
table {
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-color:#fff;
}
.list_spaces {
    border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
    text-align: center;
}
.day_spaces {
    background-image: url("../../Content/linen.png");
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.cal_spaces {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    vertical-align: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
    border-top: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
    border-right: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
    border-left: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.cal_date_nums {
    text-align: right;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #999999;
    opacity: 0.58;
    right: 12px;
    top: 12px;
}
.cal_event_links {
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.cal_actual_links {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 12px;

}
.fix_cells {
    width: 100px;
    height: 114px;
}
```

Javascript that generates the table:

```
    function loadCalendar(cd) {
    document.getElementById("my_disp").innerText = findMonthandYear(cd.getMonth(), cd.getFullYear());
    document.getElementById("my_disp").setAttribute("data-month", cd.getMonth());
    document.getElementById("my_disp").setAttribute("data-year", cd.getFullYear());
    var sd = findMonthStart(cd.getMonth(), cd.getFullYear());
    for (var i = 0; i < sd; i++) {
        document.getElementById("wk1").innerHTML += ((i === 0 || i === 6) ? "<td class='cal_spaces' style='background-color: #EDEDED;'><div class='fix_cells'></div></td>" : "<td class='cal_spaces'><div class='fix_cells'></div></td>");
    }
    var dc = 1;
    for (var i = sd; i < 7; i++) {
        document.getElementById("wk1").innerHTML += (((i === 0 || i === 6) ? "<td class='cal_spaces' style='background-color: #EDEDED;'><div class='fix_cells'><p class='cal_date_nums' style='color: #BC7777;'>" : "<td class='cal_spaces'><div class='fix_cells'><p class='cal_date_nums'>") + dc + "</p><div class='cal_event_links' id='" + cd.getFullYear() + "-" + parseM(cd.getMonth()) + "-" + parseD(dc) + "'></div></div></td>");
        dc++;
    }
    var dim = getDaysInMonth(cd);
    for (var w = 2; w <= 6; w++) {
        for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            if (dc <= dim) document.getElementById("wk" + w).innerHTML += (((i === 0 || i === 6) ? "<td class='cal_spaces' style='background-color: #EDEDED;'><div class='fix_cells'><p class='cal_date_nums' style='color: #BC7777;'>" : "<td class='cal_spaces'><div class='fix_cells'><p class='cal_date_nums'>") + dc + "</p><div class='cal_event_links' id='" + cd.getFullYear() + "-" + parseM(cd.getMonth()) + "-" + parseD(dc) + "'></div></div></td>");
            else document.getElementById("wk" + w).innerHTML += ((i === 0 || i === 6) ? "<td class='cal_spaces' style='background-color: #EDEDED;'></td>" : "<td class='cal_spaces'></td>");
            dc++;
        }
        if (dc > dim) {
            if (w !== 6) {
                for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++)
                    document.getElementById("wk6").innerHTML += ((i === 0 || i === 6) ? "<td class='cal_spaces' style='background-color: #EDEDED;'><div class='fix_cells'></div></td>" : "<td class='cal_spaces'><div class='fix_cells'></div></td>");
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < evntsInfo.evntsCount; i++) {
        var dtid = removeTimeFromDates(evntsInfo.evntsDates[i]);
        if (document.getElementById(dtid) != null)
            document.getElementById(dtid).innerHTML += "<a class='cal_actual_links' title='Submitted By: " + evntsInfo.evntsHosts[i] + "\nLocation: " + evntsInfo.evntsLocs[i] + "\nWhen: " + formatDate(evntsInfo.evntsDates[i]) + "\nTickets: " + evntsInfo.evntsTC[i] + "' href=/Home/viewTicketRequests?id=" + evntsInfo.evntsIDs[i] + ">" + evntsInfo.evntsTitles[i] + "</a>\n";
    }
    currentDayColoring();
    fixSizes();
}

    function currentDayColoring() {
        var cd = new Date();
        var dtid = (cd.getFullYear().toString() + "-" + parseM(cd.getMonth()).toString() + "-" + parseD(cd.getDate()).toString());
        if (document.getElementById(dtid) != null) {
            document.getElementById(dtid).parentElement.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = "#D7E4EA";
            document.getElementById(dtid).parentElement.firstChild.style.fontSize = "x-large";
        }
    }

    function fixSizes() {
        var mheight = 0;
        var spaces = document.getElementsByClassName("cal_spaces");
        for (var i = 0; i < spaces.length; i++) {
            if (spaces[i].offsetHeight > mheight)
                mheight = spaces[i].offsetHeight;
            console.log("mheight: " + mheight);
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < spaces.length; i++) {
            spaces[i].offsetHeight = mheight;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use chrome's F12 debugging tools. Inspect the small and large cells. Look for anything that would push them out of shape (sounds like margins or padding). *you really need to provide a HTML save-as of a sample page for this type of questions (preferably in a JSFiddle.net)* :)

Comment: I added the necessary code to my original post. Also a note: I was using jQuery's height function but my most recent futile attempt was with regular Javascript's offsetHeight.

Comment: Here's a fiddle using your code: http://jsfiddle.net/P5w7k/

Comment: @Alex Morrise: If you are going to both making a JSFiddle, please make a working one :)

Comment: The reason I didn't make a fiddle is because I'm using mvc and the function that loads the body of the page has parameters that are passed in from the model.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, I literally just made a fiddle with OP's code.

Comment: Are you saying you have dynamic/Ajaxed areas on the page, otherwise a `Save As` from the browser will give usable HTML with specific data. @Alex Morrise: I know, but that adds no value without the rest of the puzzle :)

Comment: Sure it does. It means that everybody else doesn't have to come copy OP's code into a new JSFiddle. I always appreciate it when people do it so I don't have to. Just trying to be helpful.

Comment: I'm an intern who's just learning how to use all this stuff for the first time. When the function loads it takes parameters passed from the model (server-side). I don't know if that's the same as ajax calls or not. I think the root of the problem is somewhere in the CSS though.